# Gamemode addon implementing in server

Tags: garrys-mod, hosting

I've installed some gamemodes from the workshop but I have no idea how to get this in my server.

For example I get the gamemode `Hide and Seek` which gets put in the directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\GarrysMod\garrysmod\addons`

So I copy the add on and paste it in my server hosting map which is in: `C:\Users\Loko\Desktop\steamcmd\gmodserver\garrysmod\addons`

Now I used steamcmd to host the server and use `srcds.exe` to host it.

[image]

Now I can host gamemodes such as TTT and prophunt but those aren't from the workshop. To change the gamemode I have to type in: `gamemode terrortown` or `gamemode prop_hunt`

Now I have no idea how to change it to hide and seek or murder or anything else from the workshop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extractor tool, like the one that comes with Garry's Mod by default ([official thread here](http://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=1242185)) or you can host it without using an extractor by signing up for a Steam API key ([you can get one here](https://steamcommunity.com/login/home/?goto=/dev/apikey)), creating a collection on the workshop which includes whatever addons/gamemodes you would like to host and finally, adding something like `+host_workshop_collection COLLECTIONID -authkey APIKEY +gamemode GAMEMODENAME` to the launch parameters.

You will have to replace `COLLECTIONID` with the ID found at the end of the URL for the collection you created, `APIKEY` with your Steam API key and `GAMEMODENAME` with the name of the gamemode you would like to run (eg. murder).

Answer (score -3):

Gmad extractor

1. Extract file
2. Copy to server folder

Comment: Expanding on your answer a little more would be very helpful.